# Submit an array checkbox although it's not checked

Tags: php, html

I have some multi-value inputs and there are some checkboxes among them. When I submit the form, if a checkbox is not checked, it shifts up the rest of the data and misplaces inputs in other rows.

[image]

For example, if those two checkboxes are not checked in the middle, when I use a foreach loop, it uses the fourth `hazardous` input in the second row and data is misplaced in database.

Here is my code:

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="description_of_goods_fa[]"
           class="form-control">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="hs_code[]" required
           title="HS Code needs to be a 8 digit number"
           class="form-control" pattern="[0-9]{8}">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="stackable[]" class="form-control"
           value="1" checked>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hazardous[]" class="form-control"
           onchange="check_hazardous(this);" value="1">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="number" name="un[]" min="0" max="9999" step="1"
           class="form-control" readonly>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="number" name="imco_class[]" min="1" max="9.9"
           step="0.1" class="form-control" readonly>
</td>
```

And I use a foreach loop to go through `$_POST` in php:

```
foreach($_POST['hs_code'] as $key => $hs_code)
{
    $description_of_goods_en = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['description_of_goods_en'][$key]);
    $description_of_goods_fa = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['description_of_goods_fa'][$key]);
    $hs_code = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['hs_code'][$key]);
    $hs_code = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['hs_code'][$key]);
    $stackable = (isset($_POST['stackable']) ? '1' : '0');
    $hazardous = (isset($_POST['hazardous'][$key]) ? '1' : '0');
    $un = (isset($_POST['un'][$key]) ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['un'][$key]) : "");
    $imco_class = (isset($_POST['imco_class'][$key]) ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['imco_class'][$key]) : "");
    $no_of_unit = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['no_of_unit'][$key]);
    $unit_price = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['unit_price'][$key]);
    $total_price = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['total_price'][$key]);
    $no_of_packages = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['no_of_packages'][$key]);
    $kind_of_packages = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['kind_of_packages'][$key]);
    $pkg_length = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pkg_length'][$key]);
    $pkg_width = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pkg_width'][$key]);
    $pkg_height = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pkg_height'][$key]);
    $pkg_volume = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pkg_volume'][$key]);
    $total_volume = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['total_volume'][$key]);
    $pkg_net_weight = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pkg_net_weight'][$key]);
    $pkg_gross_weight = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pkg_gross_weight'][$key]);
    $total_net_weight = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['total_net_weight'][$key]);
    $total_gross_weight = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['total_gross_weight'][$key]);
    $chargeable_weight = (isset($_POST['chargeable_weight'][$key]) ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['chargeable_weight'][$key]) : "");
    if($hs_code != '' || $no_of_packages != '' || $description_of_goods_en != '' || $volume != '')
    {
        $sql = "
            INSERT INTO `inquery_cargo` SET
                `id_inquery`='$id_inquiry',
                `description_of_goods_en`='$description_of_goods_en',
                `description_of_goods_fa`='$description_of_goods_fa',
                `hs_code`='$hs_code',
                `stackable`='$stackable',
                `hazardous`='$hazardous',
                `un`='$un',
                `imco_class`='$imco_class',
                `no_of_unit`='$no_of_unit',
                `unit_price`='$unit_price',
                `total_price` = '$total_price',
                `no_of_packages`='$no_of_packages',
                `kind_of_packages`='$kind_of_packages',
                `pkg_length`='$pkg_length',
                `pkg_width`='$pkg_width',
                `pkg_height`='$pkg_height',
                `pkg_volume`='$pkg_volume',
                `total_volume`='$total_volume',
                `pkg_net_weight`='$pkg_net_weight',
                `pkg_gross_weight`='$pkg_gross_weight',
                `total_net_weight`='$total_net_weight',
                `total_gross_weight`='$total_gross_weight',
                `chargeable_weight`='$chargeable_weight'
        ";

        $res = $mysqli->query($sql);
        if(!$res)
        {
            $text = "An error occurred during the process.";
            $error = true;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I submit those checkboxes that are not checked?

Comment: Could you post your PHP code?

Comment: Please share complete code. Thanks

Comment: @MichelleCantin My problem is more of that it misplaces inputs in rows in foreach loop because unchecked checkboxes are not submitted.

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui My problem is more of that it misplaces inputs in rows in foreach loop because unchecked checkboxes are not submitted.

Comment: And that foreach loop is in the PHP, is that right? Ok well then please show the PHP

Comment: What do you get when you print out hs_code with var_dump($_POST['hs_code']);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least two solutions

1) You should pass an index of row to form field name for each row. For example

```
<tr>
...
   <input type="text" name="description_of_goods_fa[1]"
       class="form-control">
...
</tr>

<tr>
...
   <input type="text" name="description_of_goods_fa[2]"
       class="form-control">
...
</tr>
```

So in the PHP code you can check in the loop for the existence of index as

```
$hazardous = isset($_POST['hazardous'][$index]) ? $_POST['hazardous'][$index] : null;
```

2) You can place a hidden input with name hazardous in addition to checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control hazardous-checkbox"
       onclick="changeHazardousInput(this)" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="hazardous[]"
       onchange="check_hazardous(this);">
```

So then you just need to write a 'changeHazardousInput' function that changes sibling hidden input's value

Example of the changeHazardousInput function:

```
function changeHazardousInput(checkbox) {
    checkbox.nextElementSibling.value = checkbox.checked ? checkbox.value : '';
}
```

Comment: 1) This page is totally dynamic and it creates html rows using jquery, so I can not pass an index.

Comment: what stops you from setting the name\index when creating an element with jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good way to solve your task and also to improve code readability. Just change the HTML structure to root both checkboxes under same row number. You still not receive unticked checkboxes, but since the data is grouped under line number it isn't a problem anymore.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="line[1][description_of_goods_fa]" class="form-control">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="line[1][hs_code]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="line[1][stackable]" value="1" checked>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="line[1][hazardous]" onchange="check_hazardous(this);" value="1">
    </td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="line[2][description_of_goods_fa]" class="form-control">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="line[2][hs_code]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="line[2][stackable]" value="1" checked>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="line[2][hazardous]" onchange="check_hazardous(this);" value="1">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code for html. for loop value of i will be dynamic or your definedd

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<5;$i++):?>
            <tr>

                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="stackable[]" class="form-control"
                    value="1" checked>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hazardous[]" class="form-control"
                    value="1">
                </td>

            </tr>
        <?php endfor;?>
            <input type="hidden" name="row" value="<?php echo $i?>">
```

and see below code for php file where you submit data

```
$row=$_POST['row'];
$stack=$_POST["stackable"];
$hazar=$_POST["hazardous"];
for($i=0;$i<$row;$i++){
    $stackable=(isset($stack[$i]))?1:0;
    $hazardous=(isset($hazar[$i]))?1:0; 
}
```

Its will be help full for you.